# Video.js Customizing player controls

Tags: javascript, video.js

Im Searching how to customize the player for live use with dash.js,
as browser player not work wel with live session i trying to delete seekbar and time indicators for now, in the future i will search for a seekbar that can manage live buffer.
But I can't find the correct attribute to set seekBar: false and every time indicator off,
I find this list https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-components.html but the components seems to not work.
Which are the correct attribute to exclude that controls? Or maybe is a syntax problem?

http://jsbin.com/aheVeCOG/2/edit?js,output

Volume control to false work:

```
var video = videojs('my_video_1', {
  children: {
    controlBar: {
      children: {
        volumeControl: false 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

My try don't work

```
var video = videojs('my_video_1', {
  children: {
    controlBar: {
      children: {
        ProgressControl: false 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Massimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was instructed to use the CSS side to show/hide any undesirable values.

So, I've been using the top four lines in style defn below for mine:

```html
<style>
  .video-js .vjs-current-time { display: block; }
  .video-js .vjs-time-divider { display: block; }
  .video-js .vjs-duration { display: block; }
  .video-js .vjs-remaining-time { display: none; }
  
  #.video-js .vjs-mute-control { display: none; }
  #.video-js .vjs-volume-menu-button { display: none; }
  #.video-js .vjs-volume-bar { display: none; }
  #.video-js .vjs-progress-control { display: none; }
</style>
```

The bottom-four lines (after removing leading '#' char) should work for you.
(Note that you can peruse the linked file 'video-js.css' for current defns.

Comment: Thanks Dave, it work prefectly! in my case now i have play/pause, volume and full screen button, in line from left to right in the bottom, may i ask how to postioning the fullscreen button in the opposite side:right bottom?

Comment: Yes, add a line ".video-js .vjs-control-bar { justify-content: flex-end;}"

Answer (score 3):

Just need to fix typo it works, use lowserCase at first character instead:
**progressControl** instead of **ProgressControl**

```
var video = videojs('my_video_1', {
  children: {
    controlBar: {
      children: {
        progressControl: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Working example:
http://jsbin.com/damahev/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
this.video = videojs('some-id', {
  bigPlayButton: true,
  controlBar: {
    fullscreenToggle: false,
    pictureInPictureToggle: false,
    remainingTimeDisplay: false,
    volumePanel: false,
    currentTimeDisplay: true,
    timeDivider: true,
    durationDisplay: true
  }
})
```

To make currentTimeDisplay, timeDivider and durationDisplay to work you also need to add this CSS:

```
.vjs-current-time {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.vjs-time-divider {
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.vjs-duration {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```